# best way of setting up a phonegap multiplatform project repository

Tags: android, ios, git, svn, cordova

What is the best way of setting up a multi-platform (iOS/Android) phonegap repository (git or svn). How do you handle mutually exclusive file/folders inside the the www folder specifically javascript plugin files.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this link here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

It has some really good information on installing a command line tool and doing exactly what you are talking about.  You'll need node.js installed(actually you'll need its npm which comes with node), if you don't have this you can find installation instructions on the Node.js site and it's a really cool project as well.  After that you can create a project from the command line, add platforms, plugins, and it creates a merges folder that you can use to add in platform specific JavaScript or css.